# Subscribe / Resubscribe to an Observable Stream

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I have run into a problem, where I want to subscribe to an observable stream while a predicate is true and stop subscribing while the predicate is false. When the predicate at some point in the future is true again it should resubscribe to the observable stream.

### Use case:

I have my observable stream as input (`IObservable<IList<LogEntity>> items`) if I'm unable to insert the log entities into a database it should unsubscribe to the stream, and when the database is back up running it should automatically subscribe to the stream (Based on a property `IsSubscribed`) and start inserting the data.

### My own attempt:

I've already tried the following which **DID NOT** work:

```
var groups = from dataItem in items.SelectMany(o => o.GroupBy(i => i.EntityType))
    where dataItem.Any()
    select new {Type = dataItem.Key, List = dataItem.Select(o => o)};

groups
    .TakeWhile(o => IsSubscribed)
    .SubscribeOn(_scheduler)
    .Repeat()
    .Subscribe(o => Insert(o.Type, o.List));
```

Based on the property `IsSubscribed`, I want to stream to subscribe and unsubscribe. When `TakeWhile` is true `OnCompleted` gets called, and when `Subscribe` won't work afterwards. *Side note: It is an cold observable stream*

### Question:

How can I create an observable stream where I can subscribe and unsubscribe to as many times as I want (Kinda like event handlers in C#)

Thanks for helping in advance

Comment: Replace `TakeWhile` with `Where`, and remove the `Repeat`.

Comment: If I do so, will it not just discard the log entities when the `Where` clause is false?

Comment: That IS the requirements I got from you... That is the same as if you were to unsubscribe to the Observable.

Comment: If I unsubscribe from a cold observable stream the whole stream will stop on unsubscribe. I want to be able to resubscribe to the stream again in the future.

Comment: But if you subscribe to a cold Observable you will receive all events from the start of the stream...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to add
    groups
        .Delay(group.SelectMany(WaitForDatabaseUp))

```
public async Task WaitForDatabaseUp()
{
    //If IsSubscribed continue execution
    if(IsSubscribed) return;
    //Else wait until IsSubscribed == true
    await this.ObservableForProperty(x => x.IsSubscribed, skipInitial: false)
                       .Value()
                       .Where(isSubscribed => isSubscribed)
                       .Take(1);
}
```

Use your favourite framework to convert the INPC into an Observable where you see ObserveProperty()

Basically we put inline a Task that only returns when `IsSubscribed == true`. then turn that Task into an Observable, for compatability with Rx.

Comment: Downvoter care to explain the downvote...

Comment: As I read it (and as my quick test assures me) this code does nothing. The `Do` calls a method that returns a `Task`. The `Do` doesn't evaluate the task, so it is basically a no-op. Maybe it is supposed to be a filter or some sort of thread blocking thing. Maybe supporting tests or "a working sample" would help?

Comment: @LeeCampbell My bad, seems there isn't a `Observable.Do(Func<Task>)` that I thought there was...

Comment: @LeeCampbell A fiddle of the code is availble here https://dotnetfiddle.net/pV6eol Unfortunately due to a bug in Fiddle/Nuget, it doesn't compile on their service. But if you copy it into VS it should work fine. And no...we aren't blocking any threads at all.

Comment: Yes this makes more sense (`SelectMany` instead of `Do`). Leveraging the TaskPool is a nice trick. Perhaps a rename, makes this a useful operator.

Comment: Swapped to an upvote

Comment: Having just run this through the test from the duplicate question, this "kinda" works, but due to the `SelectMany` it looses the serialization of values. In my tests (from duplicate question), it fails.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a duplicate question.

However, pulling the code from [Pause and Resume Subscription on cold IObservable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620182/pause-and-resume-subscription-on-cold-iobservable/34937480#34937480), it could be adjusted to be

```
var subscription = Observable.Create<IObservable<YourType>>(o =>
{
    var current = groups.Replay();
    var connection = new SerialDisposable();
    connection.Disposable = current.Connect();

    return IsSubscribed
        .DistinctUntilChanged()
        .Select(isRunning =>
        {
            if (isRunning)
            {
                //Return the current replayed values.
                return current;
            }
            else
            {
                //Disconnect and replace current.
                current = source.Replay();
                connection.Disposable = current.Connect();
                //yield silence until the next time we resume.
                return Observable.Never<YourType>();
            }

        })
        .Subscribe(o);
})
.Switch()
.Subscribe(o => Insert(o.Type, o.List));
```

You can see Matt Barrett (and I) talk about it [here](https://youtu.be/Tp5mRlHwZ7M?t=49m1s). I recommend watching the whole video (maybe on 2x speed) to get the full context.

Comment: Seems overly complicated...Really you just want to have a Monad that pauses execution, temporarily. `.Do()` will do that, (given the right scheduler (most of them)).

Comment: You are actually suggesting to just block a thread in the middle of an Rx query?! Seems completely against the spirit of Rx?

Comment: Actually I was proposing to use the duality of Task and Observables using the `System.Reactive.Threading.Tasks` namespace. Not blocking a thread, but using asynchrous waits from async/await.

Comment: Then you mean `SelectMany` which will loose the serialization constraints the Rx has, but Task does not.